# All NAN values when filtering pandas DataFrame to one column

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe, nan

I'm importing data from a [.csv file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1pGvUWDJv6Xr4tDhtpaw2EPmxc9N7RcrS/view?usp=sharing), which is stored in one dataframe. Looks fine there:
[image]

After which I try to store only one column of the dataframe elsewhere. However, it returns all NaN values:

[image]

The exact same code works fine for a .xls file earlier in the same Python script. So I'm unsure of what is happening here. Any clarification would be appreciated. Here is the source code:

```
    # ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
print("\nSELECT Q MEASUREMENT FILE TO FIX: ")
time.sleep(1)
# Allow User to pick file that which needs X-Y data to be FIXED
tkinter.Tk().withdraw()  # Close the root window
input2 = filedialog.askopenfilename()
print("\nYou selected file:")
print(input2)
print("\n")
input2 = str(input2)

# Check to see if directory/file exists
assert os.path.exists(input2), "File does not exist at, "+str(input2)

# Import data below and store in df
print("\nImporting Excel Workbook...")
time.sleep(1)
# You can check encoding of file with notepad++
dfQ = pd.read_csv(input2, encoding="ansi")
dfQ.values
print(dfQ)  # This DataFrame (dfQ) contains the entire excel workbook
print("\n\nWorkbook Successfully Imported")
time.sleep(.5)
print("...")

# Search Q measurements CSV for "Chip ID" and matches it to corresponding
# "PartID" in the master table created from manually fixed file.
print("Matching PartID's to update proper X-Y values")
time.sleep(.5)
print("...")
IDs = pd.DataFrame(dfQ, columns=['Chip ID'])
time.sleep(.5)
print(IDs)
s = IDs.size
print("\nSuccessfully extracted", s, "Chip ID's!")
print(dfQ.columns)
```

Comment: Have you tried using `IDs=dfQ["Chip ID"]`? (This should give you a Pandas Series)

Comment: @MaximilianJanisch Great minds think alike. It terminates with a key error:
`KeyError: 'Chip ID'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your column is actually named `Chip ID` (with a space) and not `Chip ID`.

So either `IDs = dfQ[" Chip ID"]` for a Series or `IDs = dfQ[[" Chip ID"]]` should both work.

Answer (score 2):

All you have to do is:

```
IDs = dfQ["Chip ID"]
```

and you will get the corresponding pandas.series. If you want the result in pandas.DataFrame to format just do:

```
IDs = dfQ["Chip ID"].to_frame()
```

---

EDIT:

Your columns name starts with space:

```
Index(['Date', ' Time', ' Device ID', ' Chip ID', ' Lot', ' Wafer', ' X', ' Y',
       ' Q half-width', ' Q fit', ' dQ¸ %', ' Internal Resonant F',
       ' Internal Resonant A', ' Ajusted FG Ampl', ' FG Amplitude (0.10)',
       ' Forced A', ' Forced F', ' Drive Gain', ' Frequency sweep¸start',
       ' Prelim Q  half-width', ' Prelim Q fit', ' Prelim Q Error¸ %',
       ' Execution time', ' Preliminary F', ' residue', ' '],
      dtype='object')
```

so all you have to do:

```
IDs = dfQ[" Chip ID"]
```

Comment: Strange. It terminates with a key error:
`KeyError: 'Chip ID'`

Comment: do `print(dfQ.columns)` and put the result here in the comments

Comment: OH! I did that before but didn't notice a space at the beginning of the column header for ' Chip ID' !

```Index(['Date', ' Time', ' Device ID', ' Chip ID', ' Lot', ' Wafer', ' X', ' Y',
       ' Q half-width', ' Q fit', ' dQ¸ %', ' Internal Resonant F',
       ' Internal Resonant A', ' Ajusted FG Ampl', ' FG Amplitude (0.10)',
       ' Forced A', ' Forced F', ' Drive Gain', ' Frequency sweep¸start',
       ' Prelim Q  half-width', ' Prelim Q fit', ' Prelim Q Error¸ %',
       ' Execution time', ' Preliminary F', ' residue', ' '],
      dtype='object')```

Comment: @Tyler Wait you noticed it just before me (well I had to download the dataset first )

Comment: Thanks @MaximilianJanisch went ahead and marked your post as the answer. Many thanks to both you and Massifox for the help. I'm a newbie to Python and little things like this are my weakness right now. Cheers

Comment: @Tyler You're welcome and I'm glad that we could resolve your problem so easily